# Error when stemming a word in a dataframe

Tags: r, stemming

I create a function `stemm_DF` which adds a new colmumn to a dataframe (this dataframe contains a colmun called words).

The structure of the dataframe is :

```
 word         positive.polarity       negative.polarity 
1 interesting                 1                 0                          
2      boring                 0                 1
```

The function of stemm_DF is below :

```
require(SnowballC)
stemm_DF <- function(sentiment_DF){
  sentiment_DF["stem"] <- NA # That creates the new column named "stem" filled with "NA"
  text <- sentiment_DF["word"]
  sentiment_DF$stem <- wordStem(text, language = 'en')
  return (sentiment_DF)
}
```

My problem is that when I run the r code I get this dataframe :

```
> stemm_DF(sentiment_DF)
         word positive.polarity negative.polarity       stem
1 interesting                 1                 0 c(2, 1, 3)
2      boring                 0                 1 c(2, 1, 3)
3      pretty                 1                 0 c(2, 1, 3)
```

I don't know whey I get these c(2, 1, 3) in the stem column.

I expect th have this result :

```
         word positive.polarity negative.polarity       stem
1 interesting                 1                 0 interest
2      boring                 0                 1 bore
3      pretty                 1                 0 pretty
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: I think you're making it overly complicated. In base, all you need is `df$stem <- SnowballC::wordStem(df$word)` or with dplyr, `df %>% mutate(stem = SnowballC::wordStem(word))`

Comment: @alistaire thank you very much, it works :)